# Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS C# Web service Client

Tags: c#, wpf, ssl, webservice-client

I have a WPF application and that calling 4 web services (Written with Java) on the same base URL and it was working perfectly until I install google chrome. I installed chrome and I've got this error:

> Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS C# Web service

I didn't write another code. That happened for just I installed chrome then I remove chrome but didn't work and I tried system restore, uninstall eset smart security and I cleaned all windows(8.1 single languages) certificate. So how can I figure it out? Here is my web service caller

```
public string call(string url, string json)
{
    try
    {
        var webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        var key = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(LoginService.SessionData.SessionKey);
        UTF8Encoding uTF8Encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] requestBytes = uTF8Encoding.GetBytes(json);
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        webrequest.Method = "POST";
        webrequest.Headers.Add("SESSION_KEY", LoginService.SessionData.SessionKey);
        webrequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        webrequest.ContentLength = requestBytes.LongLength;
        Stream requestStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream();//here the exception
        requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);

        using (var response = webrequest.GetResponse())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var responseBuf = reader.ReadToEnd();
            String responseJson = Convert.ToString(responseBuf);
            return responseJson;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I think it is just coincidence that it broke after you installed Chrome. Likely the service has turned off SSL in favor of TLS. Try this anywhere before you make the call: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`

Comment: It worked thank you.Could you write as an answer your post ? but i didn't understand some thing, I restore the system and cleaned all certicicate why they didn't work

Comment: Are you using Cloudflare? they dropped support of TLS 1.0/1.1 last night

Comment: yes, but when did it dropped? And [this](https://qupass.com/) is my web service if you look page information the version of ssl TLS 1.3 what is wront with it and why i should use `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` if it's 1.3 why accepting my 1.2 connection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By my observation there are a large number of services over the last several months that are turning off SSL and/or older TLS versions to mitigate security problems inherent in them.

Anywhere within the AppDomain you can just force the connection to use TLS 1.2 like this:

`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`

You can also `OR` together multiple versions if you need to support older ones as well:

`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`

Comment: I have a method that checking  payment is true or false for every one second but i can't see any response on fiddler after add your code to my project what happened now why i can't see any response/request ? or how can i see them ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know. You probably need to configure Fiddler somehow but I wouldn't know how.